# Can't create docker image for raspberry pi with angular app

Tags: angular, docker, raspberry-pi, dockerfile, raspbian

A few months ago I had my Angular test sample application running on my Raspberry pi on docker container.
The angular for testing purposes is simply a newly created Angular app, without any customization.

```
ng new exampleHelloDocker
```

For the Dockerfile I used the following three lines. Here it was important that I used the image for ARM system.

```
FROM arm32v7/alpine  
COPY /dist/ExampleHelloDocker /usr/share/nginx/html  
EXPOSE 80
```

Before I created the Docker image, the Angular app was built.

```
ng build --prod
```

I was then able to create the Docker image.

```
docker build -t example-hello-docker .
```

I'll spare the description of how to upload this to Docker Hub at this point.
Up to here, this had worked and if I set this for the Windows system, the image also goes.

I have already searched for another solution, unfortunately, the others have also left this question unanswered. Unfortunately, I only know the basics of Docker.
Maybe the solution is simple, but so long I continue to read the documentation.

Currently I use:

- Windows 10 Build 19042
- Angular 9.0.7
- Docker Desktop 3.0.0 (Docker Engine 20.10.0)
- Raspbian (Raspbian GNU/Linux 10)

What has changed?
The Docker Desktop version is more recent. Since then, building a Docker image with Angular App takes significantly longer. This could be narrowed down to the virus scanner, because when that is turned off, it runs at the usual speed.
Another noticeable thing is that the Docker image is smaller (less than 3MB).

What have I missed?

Comment: Hi, do you have your .dockerignore file? since you are passing project directory (`.`), `dockerignore` should include `**/node_modules` because otherwise docker will process it and there is no need to. building Angular is happening in your host so it's not related to Docker and only thing I can see is copying to Docker which should take only few seconds.

Comment: Hi @EricAska, I have not deposited a dockerignore file. As I already indicated in my description, deployment works for x86 or x64 systems. All necessary content is copied if I use nginx:1.17.1-alpine. But if I want to use arm32v7/nginx, then apparently the Angular app is not copied. So your description about dockerignore I don't understand how you mean that. Can you explain that why I should put the necessary directory in the dockerignore file? This sounds contradictory to me.